How to get virtualSelectInput() options to extend past the bslib sidebar?
Once I open the dropdown, I would like the full item name to be visible, i.e. overflowing the dashboard's body. The names are cut at the sidebar border by default.
I'd love to develop my front-end skills to where I can solve this on my own. But currently I cannot solve it despite seeing similar examples like this one.
A solution with an explanation of how to tackle such problems would be much appreciated.
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

vec_long_items <- sapply(1:10, function(i) {
  paste(sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
})

shinyApp(
  ui = page_sidebar(
    title = "Long items to select",
    sidebar = sidebar(
      virtualSelectInput(
        inputId = "in1", 
        label = "Input 1", 
        choices = vec_long_items, 
      ),
    ),
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$out_text <- renderTable(data.frame(items = vec_long_items))
  }
)


Not sure what you are trying to do here. Can you give more context?

@Chris Please see edits above.

Okay, not my idea of 'overflow', likely there is some 'relative' sidebar size settings, though that would contend with the concept that sidebars are less than bodies.

So your goal is here to make it work using a virtualSelectInput? Because with a pickerInput it works as in your linked question without a problem. Also I don't understand why you set label = "shinyWidgets::pickerInput" above. You should make your question more specific, omit R shiny input and specify which input.

@Jan No, any input. With a pickerInput, it does not work either. The reason is I'm using bslib. Label corrected.

Okay, I see. Using the linked answer, you need to go on .sidebar in css, then it works for a pickerInput as described for the bslib sidebar.

@Jan I've tried that to no avail. What do you mean?


css <- ".sidebar {overflow: visible !important;}", 2) tags$head(tags$style(HTML(css))) in page_sidebar() and 3) options = pickerOptions(dropdownAlignRight = TRUE) in pickerInput().


@Jan Ah, I had my tags$head inside the header argument. My bad. That works indeed but do you know why it won't work for virtualSelectInput?

@Chris I'm not sure what you mean. But I'm relatively new to CSS.

The elements of the virtual select are displayed in a dropbox-container and depending on your current view this can be above or below the dropdown. You can override the css properties width and max-width of these two selectors:
.vscomp-dropbox-container.pop-comp-wrapper.position-top,
.vscomp-dropbox-container.pop-comp-wrapper.position-bottom 
  {
    width: fit-content !important; /* make boxes fit their content */
    max-width: unset !important;   /* overwrite default max-width for larger boxes */
  }

And then we need one additional adjustment: A virtual-select has a dropBoxWrapper property which defines the parent element to render the dropbox. This is set to self by default and we set this to body, i.e., we set
dropboxWrapper = "body"

in the virtualSelectInput. This makes the dropbox not getting limited by the sidebar.

library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)

vec_long_items <- sapply(1:10, function(i) {
  paste(sample(letters, 100, replace = TRUE), collapse = "")
})

css <- "
.vscomp-dropbox-container.pop-comp-wrapper.position-top,
.vscomp-dropbox-container.pop-comp-wrapper.position-bottom 
  {
    width: fit-content !important; 
    max-width: unset !important;
  }"

shinyApp(
  ui = page_sidebar(
    title = "Long items to select",
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML(css))
    ),
    sidebar = sidebar(
      virtualSelectInput(
        inputId = "in1", 
        label = "Input 1", 
        choices = vec_long_items,
        dropboxWrapper = "body"
      ),
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    output$out_text <- renderTable(data.frame(items = vec_long_items))
  }
)


How did you even begin to solve this? I'm guessing you found .vscomp-dropbox-container.pop-comp-wrapper through Inspect?

Yes, you are right, I had to inspect this for getting the selector.

Do you know why the selector is so long? Finally, I don't understand the dropBoxWrapper property you linked. What do self and body mean in this context?

Concerning the selectors please inspect the DOM. If you e.g. have .vscomp-dropbox-container, how do you distinguish the one above the dropdown from the one below the dropdown? You need an additional class. Regarding the dropBoxWrapper think of the parent of the dropbox. self refers to the input itself whereas body refers to the body of the document.

Currently the width changes, as one scrolls, depending on the width of the options. E.g. withvec_long_items <- c(letters, vec_long_items).
Is there anyway to prevent this? Set the max width to that of the widest option?

Good point, but please ask a follow-up question on this because this is more an e.g. css or js thing rather than How to get virtualSelectInput() options to extend past the bslib sidebar?
